# Align page content

Tags: html, alignment

I have web page with centered content.When browser window is resized - it is possible to have window width small than page content. In this case page content is not centered - it is left aligned. Is there a way to right align it if no space to show it centered?

**UPDATE:**
Main goal is to keep right part of page visible when don't have enought width of window.
Something like: scrolled to right, but without code. Code make some nasty jumps when resize.

Comment: This does not seem to be something straight forward. It depends on your page's HTML code. Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: I have ony one DIV element with align="center". Nothing more to control align.

Comment: The align property is deprecated. Maybe that property is actually not doing what you were expecting it to do. I never used it, so I cannot tell you for sure.

Comment: you have to play with % instead of px for width and height in the page. But you have to be sure with images not getting overlapped when resize (If you have images loaded in page)

Comment: Tried with <center>. Result is same - center on big screen and left aligned on small.

Comment: <center> is deprecated. Check the w3c specification . All presentational tags have been deprecated. You are now supposed to use CSS instead.

Comment: Tried with css before this deprecated stuff. Same story - they all center perfectly, but left align when small window.

Comment: What did you use with CSS?

Comment: providing us your code or an illustration image would be better as we can understand what's your real problem is :)

Comment: width:900px;: 0 auto; for DIV; and    text-align: center;n in body

Comment: You cannot do those kinds of stuff in the body tag. You have to use a wrapper div (or any other block tag).

Comment: @Kostadin did you try MassivePenguin's idea?

Comment: Look at question update. I'm using wrapping div.

Comment: try @MassivePenguin 's idea then tell what you got.

Comment: Yes. Opened link from MassivePenguin - when resize result window - content is left aligned. In small window I need right aligned

Comment: Drag the window separator on the fiddle to make the content pane smaller. Trust me, it works!

Comment: Tried. Content appears left aligned. Chrome browser.

Comment: Really? >900px: http://i.imgur.com/nSFqXYD.png < 900px: http://i.imgur.com/xrznqGD.png  

I'm also using Chrome on Windows 7...

Comment: Made more test with link http://jsfiddle.net/NXdYk/2/. Yes it make content right aligned, but inside wrapper div I have table. Table content cannot be rearanged like that. My case is - when width of window is not enought - to keep right parth of content visible. Somethink like keep page scrolled to right, but with javascript this produces jumps :( Not looking good.

Comment: Ah, well you didn't mention the table. That causes all sorts of complications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set a min-width on the container, and use a media query to kick in when the window gets smaller...

```
#my_div { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; min-width: 900px; background: #999; }
@media all and (max-width: 899px){
    #my_div { text-align: right; background: red; min-width: auto; }
    #my_div #tableWrapper { overflow: auto; }
}
```

You shouldn't need the `text-align` on the `body` tag with this code. If you don't want the content to resize when the window gats smaller, remove `min-width: auto` from the `#my_div` rules inside the media query.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NXdYk/2/

EDIT:

You can wrap a table in another div, and set `overflow: auto` to allow scrolling if the window gets too narrow:

http://jsfiddle.net/NXdYk/6/

But if the table is your primary layout, and it has widths set explicitly (i.e. inline CSS) then this is a sub-optimal solution. Bottom line: you can't control how people will interact with your site, all you can do is try and plan accordingly.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I still don't have enough info to make sure that that can work for his HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example if this is what you're looking for, js script makes it work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).resize(function() {
                if($(window).width() < $('#content').width()) {
                    $('#content').addClass('fr');
                } else {
                    $('#content').removeClass('fr');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content{
                text-align: center;
                min-width: 500px ;
                margin: auto;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .fl{
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_lte6.css" /> <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">something</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants. Specially with a float and jQuery to the mix.

Comment: This code is my plan B. But still hope to make it without code.

Comment: @brunoais 'Specially with a float and jQuery to the mix' What that means? Is it bed to use jQuery or css float?

Comment: We better keep each one of those 3 in their very own realm as much as possible.